# TypeScript and tsconfig.json file for NuxtJS

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js

I have a project with **NuxtJS** (*in ./src/client/*) and **NestJS** (*in ./src/server/*).

The **tsconfig.json** for **NuxtJS** is an extension of **tsconfig.json** for global project.

I don't know how I can do to the project works.

https://github.com/pirmax/nuxt-and-nest/tree/develop

I have an error on NuxtJS when I go to root page:

> bundle export should be a function when using { runInNewContext: false
>   }.

If I delete all traces of **NestJS** in my project, **NuxtJS** starts well, but when I add my configurations in **tsconfig.json**, the project gives me this error.

## My tsconfig.json in ./src/client/

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "es2015"],
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitThis": false,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./*"]
    }
  }
}
```

## My tsconfig.json in ./ (root)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es2015"],
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": [
        "./*"
      ],
      "@app/*": [
        "./src/client/*"
      ],
      "@server/*": [
        "./src/server/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/server/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/1q478mzyvj) is the example I put together which is showcasing use of Typescript with Nuxt.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to specify custom `tsconfig.json` to `Nuxt App`. There is an option https://typescript.nuxtjs.org/guide/setup/#typecheck in `nuxt.config.json` which allows to point `Nuxt` to your `tsconfig.json` like this:

```
typescript: {
  typeCheck: {
    typescript: {
      configFile: './tsconfig.nuxt.json'
    }
  }
},
```

Other options https://github.com/TypeStrong/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin#typescript-options